# How to read rss feeds data in windows phone using c#.NEt?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rss

I have the following rss feed and it has information about other rss feeds and ultimately it will have data .
when user selects any rss feed(i want to display the root rss feed's child rss feeds by their names )the information about the selected rss feed will be shown.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/rss/feeds_rss_cricket.html

```
 public static void Read(string url)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri( url));            
    }

 static void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        //return (from descendant in document.Descendants("item")
        //        select new RssNews()
        //        {
        //            Description = descendant.Element("description").Value,
        //            Title = descendant.Element("title").Value,
        //            PublicationDate = descendant.Element("pubDate").Value
        //        }).ToList();
    }
```

I tried the below code but it shows an exception.Any idea how to fix this ?

exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code(including xml parsing) works fine, but your url points to *an html page that contains urls of rss feeds*, not to an rss feed.

try, for ex, this url. http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/1.xml taken from that page.